# How do I make a field reference another field which is not a primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I know that foreign keys need not reference only primary keys but they can also reference a field that has a unique constraint on it. For my scenario, I am setting up a quiz where for each test, I have a set of questions. My table design is like this[image: Table design here]

The point is, in my 2nd table where I will put all the answer options, I want the question number field to link to the first table question number. How do I do this? Or is there an alternative to this design?

Thank you

Comment: The column doesn't have to have a unique constraint, it just has to have an index. Although it usually doesn't make sense to reference a non-unique column.

Comment: It seems that the combination of `testid` and `question_no` is the `test_question` table's primary key. So you can of course reference the pair in a foreign key in the the `test_answer` table.

Comment: @Barmar The SQL standard requires that a FK referenced column list appears in a UNIQUE constraint. (Even though the referenced set only needs to be a superset of some unique set.) Indexes are not part of the SQL standard. Some DBMSs allow FKs to column lists not in a UNIQUE constraint. Possibly limited to those in indexes. (Unique or not.) (Although a non-unique target doesn't make sense as a FK, it still makes sense as a constraint/limitation to interpret it as requiring that a non-null subrow in the referencing table is in the referenced table.)

Comment: @philipxy AFAIK MySQL doesn't enforce those requirements.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah MySQL allows referencing indexes & referencing non-unique (and doesn't act properly in the latter case).

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally there should be a `question_id` primary key column in the `test_question` table, and you would use this as the foreign key in the `test_answer` table.

With your composite primary key in the `test_question` table, you should make a corresponding composite foreign key:

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (test_id, question_no) REFERENCES test_question (test_id, question_no)
```

This is in addition to the foreign key just for the `test_id` column.

Comment: @Bramar, yeah testid can make reference to the above table but the issue is that a testid will have several question_no. It won't uniquely identify a question

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood. There should be a `question_id` column in the `test_question` table.

Comment: I considered this too. U mean to say put it as a primary key?

Comment: yeah but is this possible? Like question_no is just a normal field

Comment: It's part of a composite primary key, so it will be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Add another table purely for answers, and link them via the question_no field.

A DB table should hold information on one sort of item. Questions and answers are separate sorts of information so should be in separate tables. Adding a separate table also allows changes to questions and answers independently. Additionally, if they are separate, you could add a `language` field to each table and have a multi-lingual quiz

Comment: @DaveyRoy, yeah but still I will have to make the link between the question_no fields. How do I do this as it is not a primary key or unique?

Comment: I like the table design as is. It ensures in a simple way that each question has exactly one correct answer. I would call the other table `test_wrong_answer` though, to make it clear only wrong answers are in there.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

You can `JOIN` on *any* columns or expressions.  There is no "requirement" for a `FOREIGN KEY`, `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE`, or anything else.

**Long answer:**

However,...  For performance (in large tables), some things make a difference.

If you are `JOINing` to a PK, Unique key, or even an indexed column, the query cold run faster.

Why have a `FOREIGN KEY`?  An FK is two things:

- A "constraint" that says that the value must exist in the other table.  Also, with things like `ON DELETE CASCADE`, it can provide actions to take if the indicated row is removed.  The constraint requires looking in the other table each time a write occurs (eg `INSERT`).
- An Index.  That is, specifying a FK automatically adds an INDEX (if not already present) to make the constraint faster.

**Getting the id**

Here is the "usual" way to do a pair of inserts, where you need the second to 'point' to the first:

```
INSERT INTO t1 ...  -- with an AUTO_INCREMENT id
grab LAST_INSERT_ID()  -- that id
INSERT INTO t2 ...  -- and include the id from above
```

For `AUTO_INCREMENT` to work it must be the first column of some key.  (Note: a `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` is a key (aka `INDEX`).)

*Optionally* you can specify a FK on the second table to point out the connection between the tables.

And, as spelled out in other answers, a FK could involve more than one column.

**Entities and Relations**

Sometimes, a set of tables like yours is best 'designed' this way:

1. Determine the "entities":  users, tests, questions, answers
2. Relations and whether they are 1:1, 1:many, or many:many...  Users:test is many-to-many; tests:questions is 1:many (unless you want questions to be shared between tests).

`Answers` is more complex since each 1 answer depends on the user and question.

1:1 -- rarely practical; may as well merge the tables together.
1:many -- a link (FK?) in one table to the other.
many:many -- need a bridge table with (usually) 2 columns, namely ids linking to the two tables.